# discord.py make the say command not ping everyone

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Ok so I've tried everything for my command but nothing worked for my !say command to work and not tag @everyone. I tried doing it myself but it still doesn't want to. I'm a beginner so i'm bad but where is the problem and what do i do?
here is my code:

```
async def say(ctx, msg=None):
    if msg is not None:
        await ctx.send(msg)
        await ctx.message.delete()
        if message == "@everyone" or "@here":
        break:
```

Comment: Some hints: 1.- If you want to ignore the user if they add the everyone/here mention, why are you checking it after sending the message? 2.- Are everyone/here strings? And some tips: 1.- ```ìf msg == x:``` would only be True if the content of "msg" is exactly "x". To look for substrings, use ```if x in msg:``` instead. 2.- Do not use ```break```, that is used for breaking loops. You should use ```return``` instead, to conclude the command execution.

Comment: why do yiou use `message` if you have only `msg`? To check two string you have to check `if msg == "@everyone" or mgs == "@here":` or `if msg in ("@everyone", "@here")`. But to check part of string: `if "@everyone" in msg or "@here" in msg:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Avoid specific mention when sending a message

[discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) already has a feature built-in, to allow or not specific type of mention.

Combining [discord.AllowedMentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.AllowedMentions) and [discord.abc.Messageable.send](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send), as the following example.

```py
async def avoid_everyone(ctx: commands.Context, *message: str)
    # Disallow everyone when sending message
    allowed = discord.AllowedMentions(everyone=False)

    # Raise an exception if @everyone in message 
    await ctx.send(message, allowed_mentions=allowed)
```